# JsonSerializer can't read stream from StreamReader

Tags: c#, json, stream, streamreader

I can't get the *`DataContractJsonSerializer`* object to swallow my stream. When I execute the code with the commented-out line active, I get to see the text provided (and it is a parsable JSON object), so I know that the stream is working fine.

However, for some reason, the compiler complains that the *`streamReader`* I'm trying to shove down its throat in *`ReadObject`* isn't a *`Stream`*. Well, isn't it?!

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.StreamReader' to 'System.IO.Stream'

What am I missing and how do I resolve it?

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(...))
{
  //String responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
  MyThingy thingy = new MyThingy();
  DataContractJsonSerializer serializer 
    = new DataContractJsonSerializer(thingy.GetType());
  thingy = serializer.ReadObject(streamReader);
}
```

I'm adapting [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to work with **my** stream. Should I approach it from a different angle? If so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put in a **reader** of a stream instead of an actual stream. Skip the `using` and whatever hides behind the ellipsis (i.e. whatever you put in as an argument when you create an instance of `StreamReader`), you can probably put that into the `ReadObject`.

Also, you'll get into problems when reading the data because `ReadObject` will return an instance of type `Object` and you'll need to convert it into `MyThingy`. Since it's a nullable (I'm assuming), you don't have to type cast but rather as-ify it.

```
MyThingy thingy = new MyThingy();
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer 
  = new DataContractJsonSerializer(thingy.GetType());
Stream stream = ...;
thingy = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as MyThingy;
```

You could of course skip the next-to-last line and put the stream directly into the last line.

Courtesy of @JohanLarsson (all Swedes are great, especially those from Stockholm, like me):
In case you can't or don't want to omit the `StreamReader` declaration in your `using` statement, I'd suggest that you take a look at `BaseStream` property to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(...))
{
  DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyThingy));
  MyThingy thingy = (MyThingy) serializer.ReadObject(streamReader.BaseStream);
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to create the reader of a stream just to get the stream back out of it? Is it perhaps advised for some reason?

Comment: @KonradViltersten No I don't think so I upvoted your answer, was gonna add that to mine post but you answered before. I'll leave mine until someone says it is plain wrong :)

Comment: I don't think it's wrong. In fact, I didn't even think of using `BaseStream` so I think it's good it's here and you should definitely leave it here (until, as you said, someone cleaver comes along and bashes us both). +1 for the creativity to you. Also, I'm ripping off your hint. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been always using this:

```
 // get stuff here
 String json = GetJSON();

 List<T> result;
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
 {
      var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
      result = (List<T>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
 }
```