# How to map a data contract to refer to correct fields in a JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, datacontractserializer

I'm recieving a JSON object that looks like the example below.

> {
>   "name1":{"name1a":"value1a","name1b":"value1b"},
>   "name2":{"name2a":"value2a","name2b":"value2b"}
>   }

I've set up a data contract for it (since I only need to access a single data field at the moment) like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyThingy
{
  [DataMember(Name="name1b")]
  public string Name1b { get; set; }

  public MyThingy() { }

  public MyThingy(String name1b)
  {
    Name1b = name1b;
  }
}
```

When I've serialized the object, I try to print it out (which works, since I'm getting a string description of the class) and them the field `Name1b`. The last part doesn't work and I'm getting `null` there. My guess is that I must have mapped the data contract wrongly but I can't see how to correct it.

How should the `MyThingy` class be declared?

*My JSON object is fetched as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081550/jsonserializer-cant-read-stream-from-streamreader/14081839#14081839).*

Answer (score 0):

I would use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) here,

```
string json = @"{
    ""name1"":{""name1a"":""value1a"",""name1b"":""value1b""},
    ""name2"":{""name2a"":""value2a"",""name2b"":""value2b""}
    }";

var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer()
          .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(obj["name1"]["name1b"]);
```

You can also use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and `dynamic` together

```
dynamic  obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

Console.WriteLine(obj.name1.name1b);
```

Comment: Are you saying that it's more recommended to transform the stream I'm getting from the `HttpWebRequest` to a `String` object and **then** parse it? Furthermore - is it totally off to use the data contract approach I've made? I'm thinking that in the future, I'll probably need a more advanced parsers than getting but a single field. What do you think?

Comment: Also, I'm not allowed to install new libraries on the server. I need to resolve it using default .NET 4 (maybe 4.5).

Comment: @AndreasJohansson You have more control on the deserialization process  if you use `JavaScriptSerializer` or `Json.Net`. I would choose one of them (BTW: MVC 4 uses Json.Net by default and it is my favorite).

Comment: Sadly, I'm getting this error when trying to follow the advice. *`Attempt by security transparent method 'x.y.z(p)' to access security critical method 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer..ctor()' failed.`* It suggest that I change stuff to the AppDomain. I'm working towards a solution where I have **nada** control over the server. I need to resolve it in another way (parsing the string by `IndexOf` and `Substring` starts to look in my direction).